How do I debug Android emulator having issues with Wi-Fi?
I'm working on a React Native app (for Android), and my emulator (on Windows) fails to pass any network request.
Basic symptom: when I try to fetch in my app, I get an error "Network Request Failed". But also the emulator shows there's no Wi-Fi connection. Other notes on symptoms and attempts to fix:

My host Windows device has an internet connection;
I have some apps hosted on localhost on different ports. This post made me think that some of them may cause a conflict, and I've tried disabling some of them, but I'm not sure how to do this consistently (i.e. what ports should I ensure to be free, do I have to restart the emulator each time, etc);
I've checked AVD Manager that the device has network enabled (Edit → Show Advanced Settings → Network Speed: Full, Latency: None);
Emulator settings (the window opened by clicking "...") has only "Cellular" and "Settings" tabs, no "Wi-Fi" (is it expected to be there?); in Settings → Proxy "No proxy" is selected (see the screenshot below (1));
An attempt to open https://google.com in the WebView Browser Tester leads to the ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error;
Like I've mentioned, the Wi-Fi inside emulator is not connected. In the Settings app, "Network & Internet" shows "Networks available" (2), but inside it, none are listed (no "AndroidWifi") regardless whether I press the Wi-Fi toggle or not (3). I've also tried to press the button ("reset network settings"?) in the top right corner, to no avail.
And yeah, I've tried to restart the emulator and Wipe Data in AVD Manager. And Cold Boot Now. And restarted the bridge (adb kill-server, adb start-server).
Just in case, I've also tried setting DNS server in the host OS, but that didn't help and it is not DNS_PROBE_FINISHED or DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_-prefixed error anyway.

So my question is: how can I debug this further?
I can also provide versions of all the components, if needed (like gradle 8.5, or JDK17, or whatever is needed)
Finding #1
Not sure about the normal connection, but adb can at least proxy specific ports: reverse = from host OS to emulator, forward = vice versa.

adb reverse --list shows all the current reverse proxies (only useful when an emulator runs). Initially, I got an empty output. After another wiping data, it showed host-19 tcp:8081 tcp:8081, but the Internet is still not there.
adb reverse tcp:5172 tcp:5172 proxied http://127.0.0.1:5172 of my host OS to the same url inside the emulator! WebView Browser Tester now successfully opens it, and my app does, too. This is a semi-victory, as it allows to proxy any local server inside the emulator; however, this doesn't allow to use third-party APIs (well, without using one more proxy for that in the host OS).

(1)
(2)
(3)

adb kill-server
adb start-server

adb restart might work for you.
Also, try to change your dns address. (for example use 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1, if you are using another address)

well, thanks for reminding, I've tried changing DNS server settings, but it's not a DNS-related error anyway. I've tried restarting adb as well, but it didn't help. Anyway, I'm asking about a more consistent understanding of the proxying pipeline and how to debug it
